# Counting the number of specific characters ignoring duplicates: Python

Tags: python

I have an input like this: BFFBFBFFFBFBBBFBBBBFF .
I want to count 'B's and the answer should be 6.(ignore the duplicate ones)

How to do it in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) :

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> l = [k for k,v in groupby(s)]

>>> l
=> ['B', 'F', 'B', 'F', 'B', 'F', 'B', 'F', 'B', 'F', 'B', 'F']

>>> l.count('B')
=> 6
```

#driver values :

```
IN : s = 'BFFBFBFFFBFBBBFBBBBFF
```

**EDIT :** Also, for more extensive use, its better to use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to get `count` *for all the characters*.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(l)
=> Counter({'B': 6, 'F': 6})
```

Comment: Reader note: If you want counts for every character, use a counter object and count all characters once, instead of calling `list.count` repeatedly.

Comment: Yup, I did see that (and +1), just before closing it ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
s = "BFFBFBFFFBFBBBFBBBBFF"
f = False
count = 0
for i in s:
    if f and i == 'B':
        continue
    elif i == 'B':
        count += 1
        f = True
    else:
        f = False
print(count)
```

another

```
from itertools import groupby
count = 0
for i,_ in groupby(s):
    if i == 'B':
        count += 1
print(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set a counter and a flag variable. Then count only occurences which are not duplicates, and flip the flag. The logic is simple: if current letter is 'B', and you the letter before isn't 'B' (dup = False), then count it + flip the boolean:

```
s = 'BFFBFBFFFBFBBBFBBBBFF'

count = 0
dup = False
for l in s:
    if l == 'B' and not dup:
        count += 1
        dup = True
    elif l != 'B':
        dup = False

# count: 6
```

Answer (score 1):

We can remove consecutive dups and use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the B's that are left:

```
from collections import Counter

def remove_conseq_dups(s):
    res = ""
    for i in range(len(s)-1):
        if s[i] != s[i+1]:
            res+= s[i]
    return res

s = "BFFBFBFFFBFBBBFBBBBFF"
print(Counter(remove_conseq_dups(s))['B']) # 6
```

And a [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) solution:

```
from itertools import groupby

s = "BFFBFBFFFBFBBBFBBBBFF"
print(sum(map(lambda x: 1 if x == 'B' else 0, [x for x, v in groupby(s)])))
```

Or

```
print(len(list(filter(lambda x: x == 'B', [x for x, v in groupby(s)]))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution by first removing duplicates using RE-library:

```
import re

l1 = "BFFBFBFFFBFBBBFBBBBFF"
l2 = re.sub(r'([A-z])\1+', r'\1', l1) # Remove duplicates

l2.count("B") # 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to count when the letters change from F to B, and another function can do that : `split`. It removes all Fs, but create empty strings for consecutive Fs, so we must remove them from the count.

```
s = "BFFBFBFFFBFBBBFBBBBFF"                                                                                                                                                             
t = s.split('F')                                                                                                                                                                        
n = sum([1 for b in t if len(b) > 0])                                                                                                                                                   
print(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution:

```
s = 'BFFBFBFFFBFBBBFBBBBFF'
l = [c for i,c in enumerate(s) if s[i-1] != c]
l.count('B') #or use counter
>>>6
```